# Is it possible to open a file named feature.xml in the XML Editor of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I have project in Eclipse that contains a file named "feature.xml". If I open the file Eclipse uses the Feature Manifest Editor. In my case this file has nothing to do with Eclipses features and I simply want to open it in the XML Editor. If I try this I get a dialog informing me of "Unsupported content type in editor."

I have tried various combinations of Content Type and File Association in the Preferences but am unable to get anywhere.

Is it possible to open a file named feature.xml in the XML Editor of Eclipse?

I am using Kepler.

Comment: Right-click/Open With.../Text Editor.

Comment: That gives me the Text Editor. Right-click/Open With.../XML Editor gives me the  "Unsupported content type in editor." dialog followed by the content in the Text Editor.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's a low-level bug in the XML Editor that the PDE editors are side-stepping. This causes the error message you see to appear. [original bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=239115) It may have been fixed in the interim, but there would need to be a thorough review to make sure the original issues didn't resurface.